# Error "Function was not declared in this scope", even though it is

Tags: c, error-handling

Function listLength() is not declared in this scope according to the compiler.   But it is declared before the main() function.
I can see nothing wrong with the function even though I've looked at other people's questions.

What's wrong with the code?

```
/* ... */

int listLenght(node* head){
    node *temp = head;
    int length;
    while(temp->next != NULL){
        length++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return length/2;
}


void createList(int length, node *head){
    node *temp = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        temp->next = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = i;
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
}


...


int main(){
    node *head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    createList(5, head);
    int a = listLength(head);
}
```

Comment: do you know how to use a debugger? see your function name!

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri Could you explain how to use a debugger to find this. Wouldn't it require successfully building it first...

Answer (score 4):

`listLength()` is not defined.
`listLenght()` is.

Finding this kind of little mistake is easy by at first believing the compiler, or trying to prove it is wrong.
I.e. search for "listLength" and see that it is inside your code ... just not anywhere apart from the call the compiler is complaining about.
Or (nice input by Martin James), go the other way round, take the "undefined symbol" complained by compiler about and paste it where it is "obviously identically" defined. "It's amazing how often that clears up the issue" (quote by Martin and I totally agree). If it does help, then there is some tiny hard to see (even thrice) difference.

'1' (digit),
'l' (lowercase 'L'),
'I' (uppercase 'i')
can be devilishly similar in some fonts.

Comment: Once I have looiked at a function declaration/definition three times, and cannot see any problem, I copy/paste one to the other.  It's amazing how often that clears up the issue:)

Comment: @MartinJames I would consider that a self-sufficient separate answer on its own. Please make one. Otherwise I offer to pick that nice advice up to integrate into mine with your (implicit) permission.

Comment: Oh - feel free!   With a clear self-documenting function name, and a few similar arguments, it's just so easy to make a silly typo and, once my brain has put in the typo, it just cannot see it when I look over what I've written, even several times, token-by-token.  So many times I've done that particular stupid, especially if a bit tired:)